# How to delete some text between the string C#

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have this kind of text:

> LINE\r\n  **5\r\n11DA3\r\n330\r\n2\r\n100**\r\nAcDbEntity\r\n 
>   8\r\n0-FD\r\n  6\r\nHIDDEN\r\n100

Take a look at the text in bold. I would like to replace the text between 5\r\n and \r\n100. I tried this code:

```
result[line] = Regex.Replace(result[line], @"((?<=5\r\n)(\S+?)(?=\r\n100))", "0");
```

But it doesn't work. Is there something wrong with my code? I was sure the (\S+?) is the problem. Any way to solve it?

Comment: Replace it with what? All `0`? One `0`?

Comment: i want to replace it with one 0

Comment: If you have to do a single replacement you may consider to use String.IndexOf/String.Replace instead of Regex. Moreover "\" is an escape sequence for regex too (not only for the compiler) so you should double them to make it a string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the code:

```
string type_1 = "LINE\r\n 5\r\n11DA3\r\n330\r\n2\r\n100\r\nAcDbEntity\r\n 8\r\n0-FD\r\n 6\r\nHIDDEN\r\n100";            
string output = Regex.Replace (
    type_1,
    "5\r\n(.*?)\r\n100",
    "5\r\n0\r\n100",
    RegexOptions.Singleline|RegexOptions.Compiled
);
Console.WriteLine (output);
```

it outputs:

```
LINE
 5
0
100,1
AcDbEntity
 8
0-FD
 6
HIDDEN
100
```

It will change all encounters of text **5\r\n - ANYTHING HERE - \r\n100** to **5\r\n0\r\n100**. If you want a more specific change please let me know.

Comment: umm can i ask what is the meaning of RegexOptions.Singleline|RegexOptions.Compiled ?

Comment: RegexOptions.Compiled is you may say my fetish - it makes the compilation and startup longer, but the runtime of a particular regexp faster by precompiling it on every start of application. You can now use also Regex.CompileToAssembly for even faster execution of regexp. SingleLine makes . match also new line symbols.

Comment: umm i still have the problem here if there are two pattern like that in a single string how do i just cut the first pattern?

Comment: Since there is no **count** option (when using also regex options) in the regex match option the best way is to add a negative evaluator to the regexp itself: change the pattern to `(?<!(5\r\n(.*?)\r\n100).*)5\r\n(.*?)\r\n100`

Answer (score 0):

If the removable Contents are Static you can use

```
s.Replace("11DA3\r\n330\r\n2" ,100);
```

Or even you can try with string.indexof

Comment: umm no it's not static, it's a hexadecimal

Comment: is it a string or what is it ?

Comment: If the Contents are changing...i don think regex will work either

Comment: the pattern is like that only the contents between those two words

Comment: Try something like this  s= s.Remove(3, 2).Insert(3, "ZX");
by using index get the middle value and insert your own